# Vertex position for linked object with armature

Tags: python, mesh, armature, geometry

I want to get the final position of a vertice with an armature. I know how to do it in a local object, but the problem is how get the final position if the mesh is linked in the scene( the typical character linked with proxy in a scene)

I can get the initial position with this code, but whithout the armature modifier.

```
import bpy

a = bpy.context.object
if a.type == 'ARMATURE':
    grpname = a.proxy_group.name

    grp = bpy.data.groups[grpname]
    for o in grp.objects:
        if o.type == 'MESH':
            print(o.name)
            data = o.data
            for v in data.vertices:
                print(v.co)
        print("===================\n")
else:
    print("No armature selected")
```

To get the final in local I have used:

```
  apply_modifiers = ['ARMATURE', 'LATTICE']
    for m in myobj.modifiers:
        if m.type not in apply_modifiers and m.show_viewport is True:
            m.show_viewport = False

    # Apply modifiers
    me = myobj.to_mesh(scene=context.scene, apply_modifiers=True, settings='PREVIEW')
    myvertices = me.vertices
```

Answer (score 1):

After ask the question, I had an idea:

```
import bpy

a = bpy.context.object
if a.type == 'ARMATURE':
    grpname = a.proxy_group.name

    grp = bpy.data.groups[grpname]
    for o in grp.objects:
        if o.type == 'MESH':
            print(o.name)
            for m in o.modifiers:
                print(m.name)

            # Apply modifiers
            me = o.to_mesh(scene=bpy.context.scene, apply_modifiers=True, settings='PREVIEW')
            myvertices = me.vertices
            for v in myvertices:
                print(v.co)

            if me is not None:
                bpy.data.meshes.remove(me)

        print("===================\n")
else:
    print("No armature selected")
```

You can use the same code that I used in local mode.